# Get path geometry from FlowDocument object

Tags: c#, wpf

Can someone tell me how to get path geometry from a WPF FlowDocument object? Please note that I do **not** want to use `FormattedText`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FlowDocument` can be viewed in any number of ways, but a `Path` is a fixed shape.  I think maybe you really want some simplified, visual-only form of a `FlowDocument`'s contents.

In that case you might try converting the `FlowDocument` to an XPS `FixedDocument` - the `FixedPage`s have `Canvas`es containing a bunch of `Path`s and `Glyph`s.

Answer (score 1):

Get the **Text** property of a **TextRange** object *initialized over the entire **FlowDocument***:

```
FlowDocument myFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();  //get your FlowDocument

//put in some (or it already has) text
string inText = "Hello, WPF World!";
TextRange tr = new TextRange(FlowDocument.ContentStart, FlowDocument.ContentEnd);
tr.Text = inText;

//get the current text out of the FlowDocument
TextRange trPrime = new TextRange(FlowDocument.ContentStart, FlowDocument.ContentEnd);
string outText = trPrime.Text;

//now outText == "Hello, WPF World!";

//to get formatting, looks like you would use myFlowDocument.TextEffects
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be exactly what we're after. I'd like Path information, not just text. I'm not interested in using FormattedText as a converter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use

> ChildVisual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Visual yourVisual)

Dunno if you can take a Visual and turn it into a path geometry..